# Braids diagrams and quantum groups

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikzlibrary

I need to include some graphical proofs of quantum groups theorem, looking like the one below:

[image: wanted]

It's very similar to the [`braids`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/braids) package, but I also need to include operators, like the S in the circle. So, is there any easy way to draw a circle in given `braids` package?

Comment: Could you give a minimal working example, drawing one of the raw pictures above with the mentioned package. This would help us a lot to help you.

Comment: Save the coordinates and add the circles afterwards seems the most straightforward. By the way, all I see under `looking like the one below` is `wanted` in red.